# Can the Visual Studio (2010) Command Window handle "external tools" with project/solution relative paths?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, alias, external-tools, command-window

I have been playing with the Command Window in Visual Studio (View->Other Windows->Command Window). It is great for several mouse-free scenarios. (The autocompleting file "Open" command rocks in a non-trivial solution.) That success got me thinking and experimenting:

- Possibility 1.1: You can use the Alias commands to create custom commands

  Possibility 1.2: You can use the Shell command to run arbitrary executables and specify parameters (and pipe the result to the output or command windows)

  Possibility 2: A previously setup external tool definition (with project-relative path variables) could be run from the command window

What I am stuck on is:

1. There doesn't appear to be a way to send parameters to an aliased command (and thus the underlying Shell call)

   There doesn't appear to be a way to use project/solution relative paths ($SolutionDir/$ProjectDir) on a Shell call

   Using absolute paths in Shell works, but is fragile and high-maintenance (one alias for each needed use case). Typically you want the command to run against a file relative to your project/solution.

   It seems you can't run the traditional external tools (Tools->External Tools...) in the command window

Ultimately I want the external tool functionality in the command window in some way. Can anyone see a way to do this? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

So my questions:

1. Can an "external tool" of some sort (using relative project/solution path parameters) be used in the Command Window?

   If yes, How?

   If no, what might be a suitable alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems as if there may, indeed, be a (much) better approach.

How about a VS extension that embeds powershell into the IDE and allows one to use DTE (Visual Studio Automation Objects)?

Yeah. That would do the trick and much more.

"[An interactive, scriptable shell](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/67620d8c-93dd-4e57-aa86-c9404acbd7b3?SRC=VSIDE)?" you ask? "Yes!" I say.

Comment: @JeffBridgman Thanks...I had seen that, but it is relevant to this (predating) discussion. If you made it an answer, I would upvote it. :D

Answer (score 2):

[StudioShell](http://studioshell.codeplex.com/) is another good, powerful, option. There's nothing quite like navigating around your solution (and Visual Studio as a whole) as if it were a file system. Scriptable of course. I've just begun to scratch to surface of this tool.